# How do I use Hibernate Indexing in Grails?

Tags: database, hibernate, grails, indexing, grails-2.0

I have read several tutorials on how to make index columns in my database. From the [Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Database%20Mapping/indexColumn.html) I know that you have to define an index column.

My question is:

1. What to do with these index columns? Do I have to use them in my queries or does Hibernate do the work for me?
2. How do I know which columns an index should contain?
3. What is the difference between: 
   `firstName column: 'First_Name', index: 'Name_Idx'` and  `matrix indexColumn: [name: "the_matrix", type: Integer]` ?

Comment: I suggest you to use data base indexing, add index in the db

Comment: @SaurabhDixit why not with GORM?

Comment: Just an FYI your first 2 questions really has nothing to do with Grails or Hibernate. Indexes are a database functionality. You should do research on indexes if you want information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What to do with these index columns? Do I have to use them in my queries or does Hibernate do the work for me?

You can treat indexes same as how you treat them in database. It will improve the speed of data retrieval operations. 
You do not need to do anything for it to work, since hibernate generates the sql at the end your database will decide how to use indexes.

> ```
> How do I know which columns an index should contain?
> ```

Depends on your knowledge of database and how you can optimize your queries, simple thing is the columns that you retrieve data more frequently might need index. If you always search for phone number, or fist name then create an index on them. All the database indexing rules are applied here as well.

> ```
> What is the difference between:
> ```

```
firstName column: 'First_Name', index: 'Name_Idx' and 
matrix indexColumn: [name: "the_matrix", type: Integer]
```

The first one is the name of the index called 'Name_Idx', which is optional. You can add more information using the second one by defining type and other information. If you allow grails to generate your database for you them it will use these information to create them.

**UPDATE**

Per your question, for creating composite index take a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510977/grails-multi-column-indexes)

The name is the name of the column [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/indexColumn.html) that you are building index on. 
Building index is more database question, you need to make them if you need them.  I am sure if you post that with sql tag you can find more information. If you dont think you need them just dont do it now, If the applications hits performance issues, then you can consider building index on your queries. fyi: Grails by default will create index for your primary keys

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why do I need a name for index columns when I never use them in queries? Can you give an example of how one would make a index of User properties firstName and lastName? Would I make a compound index column or two different?